# Parity violation

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, parity, cp-violation

I've been reading on wikipedia about parity violation in the weak force and the conclusion is:

> This implies that parity is not a symmetry of our universe, unless a hidden mirror sector exists in which parity is violated in the opposite way.

What theories cover the "hidden mirror sector" and how do they explain it?

Comment: try this https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ph/0606202.pdf